# convert object to ArrayList

Tags: c#, vb.net, arraylist

I get this error "can not implicitly convert the object to ArrayList" in a conversion from vb .net to c # (the first one does not have the option Strict activated: everything is turned off)

```
Dim archivoLeido As ArrayList = parametrosPartirDatos(0)
```

there is a large number of lines with an arrayList assignment equal to a position in arrayList in c #

```
ArrayList archivoLeido = parametrosPartirDatos[0]//<--- this is a string type;
```

even a arraylist being assigned to another method that receives arraylist as parameters:
(ModificarCamposENR(arraylist, arraylist)

```
`parametrosPartirDatos[0] = EjecutarETL.ModificarCamposENR(parametrosPartirDatos[0], parametrosPartirDatos[17]);`
```

how can I fix thoses errors?

Comment: I got a feeling you didn't have Option Strict On in your VB and would get the exact same error. Have you tried casting? Dim archivoLeido  = CType(parametrosPartirDatos(0), ArrayList)

Comment: How is 'parametrosPartirDatos' declared?

Comment: @Dave Doknjas parametrosPartisDatos is Declared as a Arraylist :D :D

Comment: @the_lotus you're right that code does not have option strict, but I don't want to cast in vb; my job is to convert vb code to c# :) ;)

Comment: The VB code (even with Option Strict Off) doesn't run without an exception on the assignment.  Are you sure your example is not missing something?

Comment: As @the_lotus suggested, you seem to have an ArrayLists of ArrayLists (even though you told me otherwise) - you really should construct your example so that we don't have to work too hard to try to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a feeling you didn't have Option Strict On in your VB and would get the exact same error. Casting in VB would look like this:

```
Dim archivoLeido As ArrayList = CType(parametrosPartirDatos(0), ArrayList)
```

In C# it would look like this:

```
ArrayList archivoLeido = (ArrayList)parametrosPartirDatos[0];
```

I would highly suggest you use List(Of T).

Comment: The OP said that parametrosPartirDatos was also an ArrayList - so both the original VB and this C# will cause a runtime exception.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas seems like it's an ArrayList of ArrayList. In VB it would work if Option Strict is off, not if it's On. It would never work in C# unless everything is casted properly. Unless I missed something.

Comment: Yes that makes sense then.

Comment: @the_lotus ...and how cast properly... in code time don't shows me error